# Find all row headers where there is overlap between specific columns in google spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

sorry if it is already answered somewhere, but I struggle to find the key words to get a solution. I have a table (in my google spreadsheet) that looks something like this

|  | Name1 | Name2 | Name3 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| A | 1 | 1 | 1 |
| B | 1 | 1 | 0 |
| C | 0 | 1 | 0 |

with more rows and columns. Now I want to give a list of names (for example {Name1, Name3} or {Name1, Name2} (which I currently do as drop-down menu cells) and get all Letters (row headers), where all the given Names have a "1" as entry.

For example:

With selection of {Name1,Name3} the return should be "A".
With selection of {Name1,Name2} the return should be "A,B".

Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```
=join(", ",
   filter(A2:A4,
      if(iferror(query(transpose({"Name1","Name2"}),"select count(Col1) where Col1 starts with '"&B1&"' label count(Col1) ''"),0),B2:B4=1,B2:B4<>""),
      if(iferror(query(transpose({"Name1","Name2"}),"select count(Col1) where Col1 starts with '"&C1&"' label count(Col1) ''"),0),C2:C4=1,C2:C4<>""),
      if(iferror(query(transpose({"Name1","Name2"}),"select count(Col1) where Col1 starts with '"&D1&"' label count(Col1) ''"),0),D2:D4=1,D2:D4<>"")
))
```